# How to capture documentary quality footage of tiny subjects

Tags: video-recording, camera, production, pro, gear

Hi, guys. I just watched the ***David Attenborough*** documentary: ***Life In The Undergrowth:

Invasion Of The Land.***

And I was wondering: What sort of equipment would I need, in order to get that kind of footage? Is it possible with typical modern retail-consumer class A/V hardware; or only at great expense - with professional, specialized gear?

I've included a short clip to illustrate the actual size of some typical subjects; followed by a copy of the entire documentary for your viewing pleasure (if anybody's interested).

Unfortunately, they're both in SD/Lo-Res; but should (hopefully) give you a decent idea of what I'm talking about.

Here's a short clip on YouTube:
[(min 144p→360p max)](https://youtu.be/OwOL-MHcQ1w)

Here's the full video on Dailymotion:
[(min 380p→480p max)](https://dai.ly/x24ghq1)

Cheers.

Comment: This is a site frequented by video professionals, you're not going to win any friends by posting pirated content. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up until the high-frame rate (HFR) section of the video I would have said that all you need is a [Canon MP-E 65mm Macro Lens](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/lenses/ef/macro/mp-e-65mm-f-2-8-1-5x-macro-photo), a nice LED light (so as not to fry the poor bugs with all the IR radiation that comes from tungsten halogen sources), and a camera with a reasonable video codec that accepts Canon lenses.  However, the HFR section is clearly in the specialized territory of a [Phantom](http://www.phantomhighspeed.com/Products/Phantom-Camera-Products) camera, which is very expensive.

Comment: Keep in mind that many recent cell phones can record 240 fps footage. Macro photography with a cell phone is tricky, but it can be done.

Comment: 240 fps is likely not fast enough to capture those high-speed sequences.  I expect they were shot at 1000fps or above.

Comment: Ah, good point!